# Why is that d3.js pie chart transition not working?

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, charts

Today I'm working with d3.js on a simple pie chart.

I used the tutorials [here](http://zeroviscosity.com/d3-js-step-by-step/step-1-a-basic-pie-chart) to build my first pie chart, yet I wanted to customize it a bit, so my code won't exactly looked like the same.

My problem occured while working on Step 6, to add some interactivity to my chart.

As shown [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/x1xD82?p=info) the pie chart should allow me to click on its legend to toggle some data. Yet, if the hover tool is working with my code (toggling effectively changes the values inside the hover box), the chart itself doesn't change.

When toggling, my browser console throws that error :

```
d3.v3.js:5737 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'data' in undefined
```

After some testing, I realised the error occured because of that part of the javascript :

```
  var path = g.data(pie(data));

  path.transition()
     .duration(750)
     .attrTween('d', function(d) {
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                return arc(interpolate(t));
            };
```

which is the same as in the demo. So, the rest of my code might occasion that error, yet I don't know what could 'cause it.

Here is what I've done so far :

Styling :

```
#chart {
  height: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 360px;
}


.tool {
  background: #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999999;
  color: #333;
  display: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  left: 130px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 95px;


 width: 80px;
  z-index: 10;
}

/* replace bootstrap css */
.label {
    color: #000000
}

/* css for the legend*/
.legend {
    font-size: 12px;
  }

rect {
    cursor: pointer;
    stroke-width: 2;
  }

rect.disabled {
  fill: transparent !important;
}
```

Script :

```
// var definition
var legendRectSize = 18;
var legendSpacing = 4;

// defines chart boundaries
var width = 960;
var height = 500;
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
var DonutWidth = 80;

// defines a charter of colors for the chart
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

// defines graphical attributes for the chart
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(radius - DonutWidth);

var labelArc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 40)
    .innerRadius(radius - 40);


var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.TST; });

// add the chart to the html doc
var svg = d3.select('#chart').append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

// add objects needed for the hover tool
var tool = d3.select('#chart')
  .append('div')
  .attr('class', 'tool');

tool.append('div')
  .attr('class', 'label');

tool.append('div')
  .attr('class', 'count');

tool.append('div')
  .attr('class', 'percent');

// loads data
d3.json("/media/Storage/bar_chart.json", function(data) {
    // creates a variable to know if a column will be displayed or not
  data.forEach(function(d) {
     d.TST = +d.TST;
     d.enabled = true;
  });
    // creates the pie chart from data
  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

    g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d.data.OPCODE); })
      .each(function(d){this._current = d;});

    // displays data on hover
    g.on('mouseover',function(d){
    var total = d3.sum(data.map(function(d) {
    return (d.enabled) ? d.TST : 0;
  }));

    var percent = Math.round(1000 * d.data.TST / total) / 10;

    tool.select('.label').html(d.data.OPCODE);
    tool.select('.count').html(d.data.TST);
    tool.select('.percent').html(percent + '%');
    tool.style('display', 'block');
  });

  // toggles off hoverbox
  g.on('mouseout', function(d){
      tool.style('display', 'none');
  });


  // add the legend to the chart
  var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')
  .data(color.domain())
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'legend')
  .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
    var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;
    var offset =  height * color.domain().length / 2;
    var horz = -2 * legendRectSize;
    var vert = i * height - offset;
    return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')';
  });

  legend.append('rect')
  .attr('width', legendRectSize)
  .attr('height', legendRectSize)
  .style('fill', color)
  .style('stroke', color)
   // function which toggles data to exclude of display
  .on('click', function(OPCODE){
      var rect = d3.select(this);
      var enabled = true;
      var totalEnabled = d3.sum(data.map(function(d) {
          return (d.enabled) ? 1 : 0;
      }));
      if (rect.attr('class') === 'disabled') {
         rect.attr('class', '');
      } else {
          if (totalEnabled < 2) return;
          rect.attr('class', 'disabled');
          enabled = false;
          }
      // defines a new way to retrieve data for the chart, selecting only enabled data
      pie.value(function(d) {
        if (d.OPCODE === OPCODE) d.enabled = enabled;
        return (d.enabled) ? d.TST : 0;
        });

      //incriminated part of the script
      var path = g.data(pie(data));

      // animation for the chart
      path.transition()
         .duration(750)
         .attrTween('d', function(d) {
                var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
                this._current = interpolate(0);
                return function(t) {
                    return arc(interpolate(t));
                };
        });
  });


  legend.append('text')
  .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
  .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
  .text(function(d) { return d; });
});
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

**EDIT :**

[Link to a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w79aytof/10/)

Since I'm using a json file I'm loading locally in my app, here I had to use a local variable where my JSON was put, yet it is clearly inefficient and brought other bugs...

Comment: Please add a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [bin](http://jsbin.com/?html,output) for your code.

Comment: @SiddP I added a JSFiddle. Yet it's not very efficient, I never prepared my code to use a local variable instead of a local file and thus this is not working exactly as it should.   Gerardo Furtado do you mean the example given with Viscosity, or the code I provided ? If it's the second case, could this mean the problem would come from my json file ?

Comment: Sorry, @Kael, my mistake, I thought the second link (the plunkr) was your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have `this._current` undefined at this line `var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);` fix it and the rest is good enough. Instead of `this.current` try with some `temp var` which is accessible in any place in the code .And you would only see transition if the `new data` is different from the `old data` try with `two sets of json and onClick` pass the new json data.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. Anyway this is not exactly my problem. Yes, I know what you mean about this._current, yet it's how it's coded in the example and it is working. Don't know why. Also, in the onClick function, data from variable pie are changed according to which data are now enabled or not. Thus this is not the problem. I managed to make the pie work, by almost using everything as in the example, now I'll just want to know : what's the problem with my code ? :(